# Откуда в выводе появляется None в python при вызове print?

Tags: python

```
def test ():
    print('test')

print( test() )
```

Есть вот такой код. Пытаюсь выполнить код и по идее на выходе должно быть слово "test", но тут почему-то ниже появляется "None". Что не так? Как фиксить?

Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш код:

```
def test ():
    print('test')

print( test() )
```

Когда вы вызываете строку `print( test() )` происходит следующая последовательность действий:

1. `print` вызывает ваша процедура `test()`.
2. Процедура `test` печатает вашу надпись `'test'`
3. Процедура `test()` не возвращает результата( нет инструкции `return`). По этому результатом работы этой процедуры будет `None`. Это значение и печатает команда `print`.

Для того, чтобы получить ожидаемый результат ваш код следует изменить например так:

```
def test ():
    print('test')

test()
```

Answer (score 2):

`none` («ничего») выдаёт вторая команда `print` — она печатает резулат выполнния функции `test`. функция у вас ничего не возвращает — вот и `none`.

если не хотите, чтобы печаталось `none`, не печатайте результат выполнения фунции `test`, а просто её вызывайте. т.е. вместо:

```
print( test() )
```

напишите:

```
test()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]:def test ():
   ...:     print('test')
   ...:test()
   ...:
test
```

Что бы понять, почему " *ниже появляется "None"*" набери
    A=test ()
и посмотри, чему равно A.

Comment: поясните, непонятно

Comment: Если набрать A= test () в менеджере переменных можно увидеть, что тип значения, возвращаемого функцией при таком способе - NoneType. Единственным допустимым значением для такого типа есть значение None.

Comment: спасибо, тебе понятно

Answer (score 1):

```
def test ():
    return 'test'

print( test() )
```